# Explicit computation of $H^2(\mathbb{F}_p^n, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology, group-extensions

I'm interested in the computation of the second cohomology group of the elementary abelian group $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$:

$$H^2(\mathbb{F}_p^n, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{F}_p^{n(n-1)/2}$$

where for simplicity let's suppose $p$ is odd.  I'm pretty sure this is right.

The following discussion of how the right hand side arises is cribbed from [*Tata Lectures on Theta III*, Mumford, Nori and Norman]; any mistakes my own.

The space $\mathbb{F}_p^{n(n-1)/2}$ on the right corresponds naturally to the space of alternating bilinear maps $\mathbb{F}_p^n \times \mathbb{F}_p^n \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  The link to $H^2$ comes from looking at the commutator map $G \times G \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ in the corresponding central extension

$$0 \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \to G \to \mathbb{F}_p^n \to 0$$

and noting it descends to an alternating bilinear map  $\mathbb{F}_p^n \times \mathbb{F}_p^n \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ on the quotient.
If $\rho \colon \mathbb{F}_p^n \times \mathbb{F}_p^n \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is an explicit 2-cocycle, then this alternating form is just
$$\sigma(a,b) = \rho(a,b) - \rho(b,a) $$
and is readily seen to be invariant under adding coboundaries to $\rho$.

So, this defines a homomorphism
$$H^2(\mathbb{F}_p^n, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{F}_p^{n(n-1)/2}$$
and it's not hard to show it's surjective, i.e., to construct very explicit Heisenberg-group-type examples of group extensions or cocycles showing that every $\sigma$ arises in this way.  It is also clear that the kernel consists precisely of *even* cocycles (i.e., $\rho(a,b) = \rho(b,a)$) modulo coboundaries.

My question is:

**Question:** can someone give me an fairly explicit proof that this map is *injective*, and therefore that $H^2(\mathbb{F}_p^n, \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ is what we think it is?

At some point a proof must use the fact that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ hasn't been replaced by, say, $\mathbb{F}_p$, as then cocycles corresponding to $\mathbb{Z}/p^2 \mathbb{Z}$ will be in the kernel.

What I would love to have, in order of preference, is:

1. an algorithm that takes any even cocycle on $\mathbb{F}_p^n$ and spits out an explicit function whose coboundary is $\rho$;
2. any proof from which such an algorithm could in principle be recovered, even if doing so involves a lot of work diving into proofs of standard results; or
3. any proof at all.

As ever, any pointers or references greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $\rho(a,b)=\rho(b,a)$, then the corresponding central extension is abelian, so you just need to show that all such extensions split, which follows from the fact that all elements of ${\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Z}$ has $p$-th roots.

Comment: Thanks Derek, that seems to do the trick.  By running the proof of the fact you mention (divisible groups are injective $\mathbb{Z}$-modules or whatever) I think I can unpack this to a constructive proof of the existence of the coboundary.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing with hindsight that this dichotomy between symmetric cocycles (corresponding to abelian extensions) and anti-symmetric ones, must be a fairly standard trope -- is anyone aware of a reference?